# f differentiable at (0,0)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $$f(x,y)=\left \{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{x^2+y^2}{sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}  & \mbox{if } 0<||(x,y)||< \pi \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x=(0,0)
 \end{array} \right.$$

Determine if $f$ is differentiable at (0,0)

Im trying to use that if the partial derivatives exists and are continuous at (0,0) then f is differentiable at (0,0) but i can't conclude. I don't even know if I'm in the right way

Comment: draw a careful graph of $z = f(x,0)$ on $x,z$ axes.

Comment: in particular, write $z = f(x,y)$ in polar(cylindrical) coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's calculate the first partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.

We have

$$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{h^2}{\sin|h|}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{\sin |h|}$$

which has no limit since the limit from the right-hand side is $1$ and the limit from the left-hand side is $-1$.  Inasmuch as the first partial derivatives are non-existent at the origin, $f$ is not differentiable there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(t,0) = {t^2 \over \sin |t|}$, for small $t>0$.

Note that $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} { f(t,0) - 0 \over t} = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} { t \over \sin |t|}  = 1$, but
$\lim_{t \uparrow 0} { f(t,0) - 0 \over t} = \lim_{t \uparrow 0} { t \over -\sin t}  = -1$.

Hence $t \mapsto f(t,0)$ is not differentiable at $0$, hence $f$ cannot be.